# Importing Node Packages in Vue without Composition API?

Tags: vue.js

I've been trying for a while to learn how to use external Node Packages, but I keep getting frustrated.

I am currently trying to implement TinyMCE. I've installed the required packages and the example instructs me to do the following:

```
<script>
 import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

 export default {
   name: 'app',
   components: {
     'editor': Editor
   }
 }
</script>
```

This is a pretty common pattern that I can never get to work, I'm guessing because I don't use the composition API. When I try to do something like this:

```
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

const messageForm = workdesk.component('message-form', {
    template: "#message-form",
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    props: ['project'],
    components: {
     'editor': Editor
    },
    data() {
        return {
            contacts: baseData.contacts,
            proposed: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
    }
})
```

it tells me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Does this mean that I need to learn Composition API to start using these external packages? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Are you using vuejs with the cdn method or with npm ?

Comment: Ah good catch, yes in this case I am still using the CDN.

Comment: With the cdn and I guess in your environment you cannot use import statements. Instead I would suggest using this in a node project with npm. If you cannot try to use tinymce-vue with jsdeliver but I could not find an easy solution or food documentation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the Composition API in order to use TinyMCE. You can try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <Editor v-model="text" :init="editorConfig" />
</template>

<script>
// we must import TinyMCE locally, or tinymce-vue will try to load it from TinyCloud and complain about a missing API key
import 'tinymce/tinymce';
// Default icons are required for TinyMCE 5.3 or above
import 'tinymce/icons/default';
// A theme is also required
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';
// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist';
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import 'tinymce/plugins/image';
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap';
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor';
import 'tinymce/plugins/searchreplace';
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualblocks';
import 'tinymce/plugins/code';
import 'tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime';
import 'tinymce/plugins/imagetools';
import 'tinymce/plugins/media';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
import 'tinymce/plugins/help';
import 'tinymce/plugins/wordcount';
import 'tinymce/plugins/spellchecker';
import 'tinymce/plugins/hr';
import 'tinymce/plugins/contextmenu';

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';

export default
{
  name: 'RichEditor',
  components:
    {
      Editor,
    },
  props:
    {
      value:
        {
          type: String,
          default: ''
        },
      height:
        {
          type: [String, Number],
          default: 400
        }
    },
  data()
  {
    return {
      text: this.value,
    };
  },
  computed:
    {
      editorConfig()
      {
        return {
          height: this.height,
          content_css: process.env.BASE_URL + 'tinymce_skin/content/default/content.css',
          skin_url: process.env.BASE_URL + 'tinymce_skin/ui/oxide',
          menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table tc help',
          toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | numlist bullist checklist | forecolor backcolor casechange formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample',
          quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
          toolbar_mode: 'sliding',
          contextmenu: 'link image imagetools table',
          plugins:
            [
              'advlist autolink lists link image charmap anchor',
              'searchreplace visualblocks code imagetools hr',
              'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
            ],
          image_advtab: true,
        };
      },
    },
  watch:
    {
      text(newVal)
      {
        this.$emit('input', newVal);
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

and also in `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports =
{
  chainWebpack: config => 
  {
    // TinyMCE - copy skins from node_modules/tinymce to the /public folder
    config.plugins.has('copy') && config.plugin('copy')
      .tap(([pathConfigs]) =>
      {
        //const to = pathConfigs[0].to;
        pathConfigs[0].force = true; // so the original `/public` folder keeps priority

        // add other locations.
        pathConfigs.unshift({
          context: './node_modules/tinymce/skins',
          from: './**/*',
          to: './tinymce_skin',
        });

        return [pathConfigs];
      });
    return config; 
  },
}
```